# Android: Auto hide Volume bar in android app

Tags: android, popup

Based on the Samsung Galaxy S8 auto-hide navigation keys, I want to make my own auto hide volume bar. It will be an app for playing TV series, made just for one particular device specific for not having any physical buttons.

Volume bar should be opened on bottom screen swipe and auto-hide in 2 sec if not used.

Something like [this GIF](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-6j1wDPA4tzc/WVAqlMYJuQI/AAAAAAAANQI/aYDosPrMh3sxVgdftxXIxB-tjsc3jdEiACLcBGAs/s1600/access%2Bhidden%2Bnavigation%2Bbar%2Bin%2BGalaxy%2BS8.gif).

How can I implement something like that in an app, not in the operating system itself?